# How to add custom prerequisites to VS 2010 Setup projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, setup-project, crystal-reports-2008, prerequisites

I have an application that needs to use Crystal Report Basic. I understand, I can add this as prerequisite and if it's not already installed on Target machine, it will be downloaded and installed.

I can't seem to find similar option on VS 2010 or maybe I forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Prequisities called [Bootstrapper Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx) packs to your VS2010 using a very good tool which is Bootstrapper Manifest Generator. here is a good [tutorial how to build custom prerequisities](http://ntsblog.homedev.com.au/index.php/2011/03/03/bootstrap-manifest-generator-2008-how-to-guide-v2/) , then you add them into Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages folder (v7.0A case windows 7 or 2008) 
Hope it helps

Comment: I found that the link to BMG2008 is broken. Here the [link](http://sdrv.ms/L5pi6b) to download it from my skydrive