# Creating installer with multiple support files

Tags: mysql, installation

I currently have a program that uses Qt, MySql, and MS Visual Studio 2010 compiler.  I want to create an installer that can be put on a fresh computer, and when opened, it will install my program plus all the needed files from the others.

I don't know if it matters but I followed this blog to install the files in the first place: http://eraden.blogspot.com/2013/05/my-fight-with-qt-5-and-mysql-drivers.html

Is there any way for my installer file to first run through the steps to install the support files, then have it install my program in such a way that the program has all the files it needs?

Thanks in advance,
-Duncan

Answer (score 0):

You need to [add the resources as prerequisites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578105/how-to-add-custom-prerequisites-to-vs-2010-setup-projects) to the main package, this will make them install before your application, so the system is ready to launch the application when the installation is done.