# how to change c# built in event behavior

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, installation, setup-project

There is a built event known as BeforeInstall now this event is not firing correctly, it fires when the msi install wizard has begun install and by then it is too late for my pre-requisites to be installed, how do you go about changing the behavior of a built in event or shall i implement my own event with an handler?

Comment: Is this your actual question: [How to add custom prerequisites to setup projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578105/how-to-add-custom-prerequisites-to-vs-2010-setup-projects) ?

Comment: yes exactly. sorry if its slightly ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

It's very badly named. It is not before the install. Everything supplied by Visual Studio where you can run your code is actually run after all the files are installed.  That's why you need a prerequisite handler, which is what Visual Studio setups provide with a standard list of prerequisites.

Although the Bootstrap Manifest Generator may still work it's better IMO to use the WiX bootstrapper. Note that you don't need to build your MSI file with WiX but you can use the bootstrapper bundle. Here are some examples and documentation:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/net-and-net/bootstrapping/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb88b2/installing-prerequisites-using-wix-bootstrapper-project-and/

Regarding the later comment about this being related to providing a prerequisite Dll, the simple solution is to add it to your setup project as a file and simply install it in the required folder. All install custom actions in VS setups run after the files are installed. You may be using some "project output" setting as input to your MSI build, but you can just add the Dll as a single file. Some Dlls have redistributable packages (merge modules or executables) to ensure correct installation - if yours is one of those this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Would I not be able to run my iis program as an embedded resource, wix is not an option as this needs to be used as a company software utility

Comment: If your program is an embedded resource, what then? Everything VS setups run as custom actions is all after the install. When the install is finished you'd run the program? But your question says before the install. WiX is just a tool that will build a bootstrapper to install prerequisites. It's no different from using Visual Setup with the prerequisites option to build a bootstrapper for a prerequisite. I guess I don't see why Visual Studio or the BMG could be used to build a bootstrapper but WiX can't. Good luck.

Comment: bootstrap manifest generator is available in visual studio 2017, not sure on how to use it fully in the final solution.

Comment: to be fair the pre-requisite is a dll, the examples shown are with .exe files so would that make a difference when compiled in the bootstrapper

Comment: I've added some more info, but basically you've asked a classic XY problem instead of just asking how to install a prerequisite Dll.  http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: ok so ive implemented a boostrapper package and i was expecting to see it in the pre-requisite dialog boxes in visual studio however this is not the case but the package appears in the register editor, not sure what i have done wrong

Comment: Note my edited answer says that if all you have is a Dll then just add it to your setup project and install it.

Comment: So I tried to get the package to appear in pre requisite list in visual studio hence why it does not install.